# undefined reference to `ROM_SysTickIntRegister'

Tags: c, troubleshooting, stellaris

I am trying to program the Stellaris LaunchPad to blink the red LED at 1 Hz, driven by the sysTick interrupt. I get an error though that I've been unable to solve yet.

The C source I came up with looks like this:

```
#include "inc/hw_gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_nvic.h"
#include "inc/hw_sysctl.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"

#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "driverlib/rom.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/systick.h"

#include <stdint.h>

#define LED_RED GPIO_PIN_1

uint8_t ledState = LED_RED;

void isr( void ) {
    ledState ^= ledState; // toggle LED state
    ROM_GPIOPinWrite( GPIO_PORTF_BASE , LED_RED , ledState );
}


int main() {
    // Set system clock to 80 MHz using PLL and external 16 MHz crystal.
    ROM_SysCtlClockSet( SYSCTL_USE_PLL | SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN );

    // Enable GPIO for LED.
    ROM_SysCtlPeripheralEnable( SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF );
    ROM_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput( GPIO_PORTF_BASE , LED_RED );

    // Enable SysTick at 500 ms and register an interrupt service routine.
    ROM_SysTickIntRegister( isr );
    ROM_SysTickPeriodSet( 40000000 ); // 80 MHz ÷ 2 
    HWREG( NVIC_ST_CURRENT ) = 0;     // A write to this register reloads the SysTick counter
    ROM_SysTickEnable();
    ROM_SysTickIntEnable(); // <=

    while ( 1 ) {}
}
```

And these are the command I use to compile it:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc \
        blink.c \
        startup_gcc.c \
        -g \
        -mthumb \
        -mcpu=cortex-m4 \
        -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 \
        -mfloat-abi=softfp \
        -Os \
        -ffunction-sections \
        -fdata-sections \
        -MD \
        -std=c99 \
        -Wall \
        -pedantic \
        -DPART_LM4F120H5QR \
        -c \
        -I~/stellaris/stellarisware \
        -DTARGET_IS_BLIZZARD_RA1

blink.c: In function 'main':
blink.c:34:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ROM_SysTickIntRegister' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ROM_SysTickIntRegister( isr );
  ^
```

and to link:

```
arm-none-eabi-ld \
         -T blink.ld \
         --entry ResetISR \
         -o a.out \
         startup_gcc.o \
         blink.o \
         --gc-sections

blink.o: In function `main':
~/stellaris/projects/sysTickBlink/blink.c:34: undefined reference to `ROM_SysTickIntRegister'
```

The `startup_gcc.c` can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/fabhack/SW-EK-LM4F120XL/blob/master/boards/ek-lm4f120xl/blinky/startup_gcc.c

1. How can I solve the warning and error message?
2. Why do I have to include `inc/hw_nvic.h` and `inc/hw_types.h` when it is also included in startup_gcc.c?
3. Why is that `ResetISR` used during linking? I copied it from the Makefile in StellarisWare.

Comment: I solved the problem described in my question. Check [my git server](http://git.linformatronics.nl/gitweb/?p=sysTickBlink;a=summary) for a working 1 ms SysTick driven interrupt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `systick.h` in my launchpad installation doesn't have `ROM_*` functions. It has these:

```
extern void SysTickEnable(void);
extern void SysTickDisable(void);
extern void SysTickIntRegister(void (*pfnHandler)(void));
extern void SysTickIntUnregister(void);
extern void SysTickIntEnable(void);
extern void SysTickIntDisable(void);
extern void SysTickPeriodSet(uint32_t ui32Period);
extern uint32_t SysTickPeriodGet(void);
extern uint32_t SysTickValueGet(void);
```

Drop the `ROM_`

Your first port of call should be looking in the requisite header file to see what the functions are you should be using.

You also need to ensure you link in the right c files from the driverlib - in this case the systick.c file.

Comment: That solves the compile time warning, but not the `undefined reference` error during linking.

Comment: See my edit. . .

Comment: Thanks. It compiles without errors now, although I don't really get why I need to include `systick.c` and `interrupt.c` rather than the `.h` versions. Next step is troubleshooting why the LED doesn't blink, but that is probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: The .h files define what functions are available for your code to use. The .c files contain the actual functions themselves.

Comment: So could I consider it a bug in the StellarisWare?

Comment: No, you could consider it a bug in your understanding of how you compile programs.  It's how C works. You include header files that define the functions, then link with the actual functions. Often the functions will be in a .a file (lots of c files pre-compiled into .o files then archived into a .a file) so you just link with that library instead of having to find the individual files.

Comment: Managed to get it working. Not quite how I thought/expected, but it looks good. The 1 Hz is too low for the 24 bit counter, I had to enable interrupts globally and the mechanism I had in mind to toggle the LED doesn't quite work the way I thought. Thnx for your pointers.

Comment: Do you have experience with TivaWare too? Is it worth to switch? Is it worth a question on the stack?